# Java. Упростить метод проверяющий что скобки "()" парные и правильно расположены не ")("

Tags: java

Мне дали задание сделать метод который будет проверять как расположены скобки в строке. Сколько бы скобок не было они должны быть все закрыты если это так то метод возвращает `true` если нет то `false`.

Я это решил и оно работает но мне было сказано что-бы я упростил чтобы был только один цикл, но что-то не получается. Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот мой код:

```
boolean checkSecond(String bracket) {
        char[] array = bracket.toCharArray();

        if (array.length % 2 != 0)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == '(') {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                    if (array[j] == ')') {
                        array[i] = '+';
                        array[j] = '+';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (char c : array) {
            if (c != '+')
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Это классическая задача на проверку баланса скобок. В цикле проходите по строке. За открывающую скобку даете 1 балл, за закрывающую - вычитаете 1 балл. Если сумма баллов падает ниже ноля или же остается больше ноля после обхода строки - скобки расставлены неправильно.

Comment: А на вход поступает строка чисто из скобок? или нет?

Comment: >>А на вход поступает строка чисто из скобок? или нет?<<да конечно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boolean checkSecond(String bracket) {
    char[] array = bracket.toCharArray();
    if (array.length % 2 != 0) return false;
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        d += array[i] == '(' ? 1 : -1;
        if (d < 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```